# Documenting `tuple` return type in a function docstring for PyCharm type hinting

Tags: python, pycharm, docstring

How can I document that a function returns a `tuple` in such a way that PyCharm will be able to use it for type hinting?

Contrived example:

```
def fetch_abbrev_customer_info(customer_id):
  """Pulls abbreviated customer data from the database for the Customer
       with the specified PK value.

       :type customer_id:int The ID of the Customer record to fetch.

       :rtype:???
  """
  ... magic happens here ...

  return customer_obj.fullname, customer_obj.status #, etc.
```

Comment: :returns: customer name: his name, customer status: his status, customer's dog's name: usually Fido.

Comment: Couldn't the whole string just be `"""Return (name, status, etc)"""`? Everything else seems a bit redundant. Unless the PK value had something to do with what kind of customer_id the function expects.

Comment: Updated the question text to be a bit less subjective.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I contacted PyCharm support, and this is what they said:

> For tuple please use `(<type_1>, <type_2>, <type_3>, e t.c.)` syntax.
>
> E.g.:
>
> ```
> """
> :rtype: (string, int, int)
> """
> ```

This is confirmed in [PyCharm's documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html):

> ### Type Syntax
>
> Type syntax in Python docstrings is not defined by any standard. Thus, PyCharm suggests the following notation:
>
> ...
>
> - (Foo, Bar) # Tuple of Foo and Bar

Comment: I think this is now broken as of PyCharm 2017.1.5