# How do I document rtype when a function returns multiple values

Tags: python-3.x, return, pycharm

I've just started using PyCharm and it is teaching me quite a bit about the correct ways to document things.  That documentation then makes the IDE more productive.  But, it's raised a question for me.

I see that there are a couple of ways to document the data type of the value returned by a function.

1. In the function definition use -> type
2. In the function comments use :rtype: type

But, how does this work for functions that return multiple values?  For example, if a function returns both a boolean AND a float, how do you document this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Documenting \`tuple\` return type in a function docstring for PyCharm type hinting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090037/documenting-tuple-return-type-in-a-function-docstring-for-pycharm-type-hinting)

Comment: The noted entry does answer the question but the answer below provides an alternate way of doing what I need that is more in line with how I am currently documenting my code.

Comment: ... it's the same answer in a different place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really simple using type annotation:

```
def func(i: int) -> (bool, float):
```

You would do something similar in the docstring.

Comment: Quick follow on question: Is there a way to indicate what each returned value represents / name the return values or is that just done in the comment block?  That would help because, presumably, Pycharm would prompt me with those names when I'm writing the code that calls this routine.

Comment: Use a named tuple. Outside of your function define: `bool_float = namedtuple('bool_float', ['b', 'f'])`. Then in your function: `return bool_float(your-bool, your_float)`. The declaration becomes `def func(i: int) -> bool_float:`.