# Type Hinting tuple

Tags: python, type-hinting

Why does this type hinting work:

```
tuple[str, str] | str
```

and this one doesn't:

```
(str, str) | str
```

Shouldn't they be equivalent?

Minimal reproducible code:

```
a: tuple[str, str] | str = ""
```

and

```
a: (str, str) | str = ""
```

I've been using this:

```
a: (str, str) = ("foo", "bar")
```

for ages and I don't know why when using the `|` operator I need to explicitly say `tuple[str, str]`.

Comment: I've never seen `(x, y)` as a shorthand for a `tuple[x, y]`.  I just tested with `mypy` and it doesn't allow it.

Comment: `a: (str, str) = ("foo", "bar")` this doesn't work on your end?

Comment: Maybe it's PyCharm allowing me to do it for no reason then

Comment: Looks like a PyCharm thing. Historically, [PyCharm did use hints of the form `(str, str)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18090037/11082165) in its own type hinting syntax, so this may be a carry-over from that. Using `(str, str)` as a type hint isn't provided by any of the [relevant PEPs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#relevant-peps).

Comment: So I should just always use `tuple[str, str]` in the future, right?